# Highlight search terms in search results in Twig/Timber

Tags: php, symfony, twig, timber

I'm working with the answer to this question [Twig highlight word (Timber plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380302/twig-highlight-word-timber-plugin) to update the function to work under the newer Timber/Twig 2 filter structure.

But I'm getting the error that "Argument 2 passed to {closure}() must be of the type array, null given".

So I know that I need to pass the search term(s) to the function. How do I do that?

Do I get search term(s)  from `{{ search_query }}` on the `search-results.twig` template?

Or are the search term(s) in a global I can get from `search.php` and the "context" call in that file, i.e. `$context['search_query'] = get_search_query();`?

I need to use the filter in the standard way `in search-results.twig`, like this `{{ content|highlight }}` as I have separate fields for the search results title and content and want to highlight the terms in each.

This function in `functions.php` currently throws the error noted above:

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function($twig) {
   $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());

   $twig->addFilter(
     new Twig_SimpleFilter(
       'highlight', 

function($text, array $terms) {

    $highlight = array();
    foreach($terms as $term) {
       $highlight[]= '<span class="highlight">'.$term.'</span>';
    }

    return str_ireplace($terms, $highlight, $text);
}

 )
   );

   return $twig;
});
```

**Update: this works**

functions.php:

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function($twig) {
   $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());

   $twig->addFilter(
     new Twig_SimpleFilter(
       'highlight', 

function($text, array $terms) {

    $highlight = array();
    foreach($terms as $term) {
       $highlight[]= '<span class="highlight">'.$term.'</span>';
    }

    return str_ireplace($terms, $highlight, $text);
}

 )
   );

   return $twig;
});
```

and in search-results.twig:

```
{% set searches = [ search_query ] %}

and

{{ content|highlight(search_query|split(' ')) }}
```

and in search.php

```
$search_results = Timber::get_posts();
$context['search_query'] = get_search_query();
```

Comment: How are u using the filter inside your template?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that; I need to use a standard filter like {{ content|highlight }}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the terms u want to highlight like this

```
{{ content | highlight(['foo', 'bar',]) }}
```

If you only have one term defined, u could do it like this

```
{% set search = 'foo' %}
{{ content | highlight([ search, ]) }}
```

---

If I were you i'd change the function to this

```
function($text, $terms) {
    if (!is_array($terms)) $terms = [ $terms, ];
    $highlight = array();
    foreach($terms as $term) {
       $highlight[]= '<span class="highlight">'.$term.'</span>';
    }

    return str_ireplace($terms, $highlight, $text);
}
```

Then u can pass a single term or multiple

```
{% set search = 'foo' %}
{{ content | highlight(search) }}

{% set searches = [ 'foo', 'bar', ] %}
{{ content | highlight(searches) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why I need the {% set searches = [ 'foo', 'bar', ] %} in the twig file. Why doesn't the {{ content | highlight(searches) }} work without it? That was what I was trying to do, pull the search query terms into the function.

Comment: It's just for example purposes, you can pass any array to your `twig` template and pass it to the `highlight` filter

Comment: Hmm... But I don't understand how to pass an array to the twig template or the filter.

Comment: I already showed u how to pass it to the filter. You only need to pass your terms from your controller to your template like u usually do

Comment: Ah, that works; I used {% set searches = [ search_query ] %} to call the search term above the filter call. It works now for one term. But if I search with two words, nothing. So do we need another function to add commas in between search terms?

Comment: What does `search_query` contain? If it's a comma/dot commna separated list you could do `{{ content | highlight(search_query|split(',')) }}`

Comment: I used dump variable and found that search terms are separated by spaces, so using `highlight(search_query|split(' '))` works. Thanks!